# Building dot net application using NANT - Error - Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath ""

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, nant

We are building .Net application using NANT script.
Already gone through solutions forsame problem, but still error persist.
Development Environment : VS 2015, Win 10. (Same process works on other machine.)

Getting following error:

```
  [msbuild] (GenerateSatelliteAssemblies target) ->
  [msbuild]   

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2863,5): error MSB3086: 
Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the 
registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". 
Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath 
and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed [D:\My_Code\Code.Core.Exceptions\Core.Exceptions.csproj]
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild]     4 Warning(s)
  [msbuild]     1 Error(s)
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] Time Elapsed 00:00:04.01
```

Comment: Nant in 2015? Id take that out of the process for a start.

Comment: The error message is issued from MSBuild. I currently have a MSBuild script that I try to execute on the same platform (win10, VS2015), issuing the exact same massage, even though I make no use of NANT (even don't know what it is !)